# Rectangular Icons in Action Bar

Tags: android, icons, android-actionbar

I need to show a rectangular icon in the ActionBar, but it resizes me to square dimensions and it becomes so tiny i can't see it.
Do anyone know a way to show it at regular rectangular size?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use an [action view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) instead of a regular action item. In the layout resource you use with `android:actionLayout`, have an `ImageView` or `ImageButton` or something that points to your rectangular icon.

Comment: This answer is correct but a bit short. Read the linked information carefully.

Comment: So you saying that it's not possible to make rectangular icon in actionbar.

Comment: using android:actionLayout doesn't show me anything. Just a blank space there